# Combining contents of two cells into one cell

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to know the following: I have an Excel worksheet in which one column can have any input and another column with a pick list. To be more specific; the pick list has data validation for weight of equipment (kg, lb, tn). Let's say I have an equipment weighing 55 kg. In the first column I just enter 55; in the second I use the pick list. Now I want to create a single cell with both these column contents. How should I do this?

Comment: You can concatenate cell values with e.g. `=A1 & B1`

Comment: this is really the wrong site for such basic Excel questions. Please take a moment to read what a site is about before you post.

Answer (score 0):

Combine with:

```
=A1 & B1
=CONCATENATE(A1,B1)
```

or with spaces

```
=A1 &" "& B1   
=CONCATENATE(A1," ",B1)
```